# Why python creating new object for string

Tags: python, string, object

```
In [38]: a = "a"
In [39]: b = "a"
In [40]: a is b
Out[40]: True
In [41]: id(a)
Out[41]: 140290557625488
In [42]: id(b)
Out[42]: 140290557625488
```

but when I am adding a special charecter, it is creating a new object

```
In [43]: a = "a@"
In [44]: b = "a@"
In [45]: a is b
Out[45]: False
In [46]: id(a)
Out[46]: 140290299739112
In [47]: id(b)
Out[47]: 140290299737232
```

why is it showing different behavior for a special character?

Comment: that's because caching is only done when chars are alphanum. Let me find the duplicate.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you shouldn't ever need to depend on this behaviour, so why are you asking?